# Cassandra DB, How to store huge mp4 files into Cassandra DB keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm currently learning how to use cassandraDB and have set up 2 ubuntu server connecting to each other.

**start node 1 on PC1**

```
docker run --name node1 -it -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=<pc1 ip address> -p7000:7000 -p7001:7001 -p9042:9042 -p9160:9160 cassandra:3.11.3
```

**start node 2 on PC2**

```
docker run --name node2 -it -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=<pc2 ip address> -p7000:7000 -p7001:7001 -p9042:9042 -p9160:9160 -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=<pc1 ip address> cassandra:3.11.3
```

I'm planning to store huge data like mp4 videos into cassandraDB and all the things I find on the internet are splitting of the video into tiny parts and storing them.

I wonder if there is a good reference somewhere that can really explain how can I split an mp4 video into tiny parts and storing them into a CassandraDB keyspace.

At the same time, how is the video is read from the DB when it is being called.

My goal is to be able to store a video file on PC1 into cassandraDB and the data will be replicated into PC2 where I can read the data out.

Many thanks to anyone who can help or teach me (:

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answers your question, but I want to point that storing huge binary data in the Cassandra isn't good practice - for blob storage it's better to use another technology, something like, S3-compatible blob storage, or something like.

Regarding your question - just create a keyspace in your cluster and tables inside. To write and read data use any of [available drivers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/current.html#current__apachecassandraossdrivers) (scroll down) in language of your choice.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for giving some advices on using other technology than cassandra to store huge data and also to read and write data using keyspaces in the cluster i created.

However, for just learning purposes. i would really love to know if there is a way that i can really store a huge video into cassandraDB, like an example stated in my question on splitting the video and storing them in pieces, but i'm not exactly sure if that will work and how the video merge back into one piece before reading it. If there is a existing coding out there or example/reference would be a great help too.

Comment: I'm not aware about such examples for splitting video - I think that you can find them somewhere. For Cassandra everything will be just a binary blob. But if you just started, you can look to https://killrvideo.github.io/ - it's good started for DSE/Cassandra

Comment: Thank you for the great advices Alex. Will take a look at that. At the same time I’ll wait and see if someone else might have some examples of storing a mp4 by splitting into cassandradb or any knowledge of a way.